# Music suddenly stops playing in application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-media-player

I have this code:

```
private void OtworzPlikButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        string directory = ofd.FileName;
        WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.URL = directory;
        wplayer.controls.play(); 
    }
```

I'm getting the file directory from the OpenFileDialog and I am using wplayer to start playing music. At first it is working good but after 20-30 seconds, music suddenly stops playing and I can't figure out why. I am playing MP3 file.

Answer (score 6):

You should create instance of `WindowsMediaPlayer` in class level scope (not inside `OtworzPlikButton_Click` event handler scope).

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer;

private void OtworzPlikButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.ShowDialog();
    string directory = ofd.FileName;
    wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    wplayer.URL = directory;
    wplayer.controls.play(); 
}
```

Comment: Any technical explanation for this ?